# jQuery execute function when a div gets empty (not onload)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div in a form which has checkboxes as options in it when the page loads. After some form fields are filled, some combinations wont allow you to check extra options because of compatibility so the options in the div get deleted.

**My question is**: Is there a way to check a specific div if it's empty after the page is loaded? So yes, execute a function.

Comment: Maybe you need to trigger your event when user fill specifics fields? Also wouldn't it be simpler/ergonomic to show extra options when user fill specific fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
let div = document.getElementsByClassName("someDiv")[0];

function someFunction() {
  alert("div empty");
}

console.log(div.innerText);

if ((div.textContent !== undefined) || (div.textContent !== '')) {
  someFunction();
}
```

```html
<div class="someDiv"></div>
```